# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) after updating Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, crash

After I updated Xcode to 9.4.1 from 9.4 and `Command Line Tools(macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode`(updated on 18 June) I am getting all the time the following error when I submit my app to review.

```
{"app_name":"MyApp.Ios","timestamp":"2018-07-01 10:10:46.55 -0700","app_version":"1.2.40","slice_uuid":"9a14ed6c-6f2f-36e9-8336-1a4b3c9598c8","adam_id":1355950508,"build_version":"1.2.40","bundleID":"com.MyApp.Ios","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)","incident_id":"A5CF0458-08A8-42BA-B9CA-65D14BF18BF4","name":"MyApp.Ios"}
Incident Identifier: A5CF0458-08A8-42BA-B9CA-65D14BF18BF4
CrashReporter Key:   2b045d46ab37908d244c6a4194a66f9b479d11ad
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             MyApp.Ios [6982]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/74539A73-C2CA-4EF8-AAB8-DCE44E4796CF/MyApp.Ios.app/MyApp.Ios
Identifier:          com.MyApp.Ios
Version:             1.2.40 (1.2.40)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyApp.Ios [3134]


Date/Time:           2018-07-01 10:10:46.4214 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-07-01 10:10:44.5776 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4368449536
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104614000-0000000104618000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  .../MyApp.Ios

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d52ec 0x1821b3000 + 140012
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182376288 0x182373000 + 12936
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182143db0 0x1820e1000 + 404912
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182143d18 0x1820e1000 + 404760
4   MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000105830538 0x104614000 + 18990392
5   MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010572aeb8 0x104614000 + 17919672
6   MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001056e0614 0x104614000 + 17614356
7   MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001056df35c 0x104614000 + 17609564
8   MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001056d6f94 0x104614000 + 17575828
9   MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010467d2a8 0x104614000 + 430760
10  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010492c6c8 0x104614000 + 3245768
11  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001056f0748 0x104614000 + 17680200
12  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010576dc00 0x104614000 + 18193408
13  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010577141c 0x104614000 + 18207772
14  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010463cc6c 0x104614000 + 167020
15  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001046500e4 0x104614000 + 245988
16  UIKit                           0x000000018c366e64 0x18c314000 + 339556
17  UIKit                           0x000000018c366a50 0x18c314000 + 338512
18  UIKit                           0x000000018cf09fd8 0x18c314000 + 12541912
19  UIKit                           0x000000018c590398 0x18c314000 + 2605976
20  UIKit                           0x000000018c58f25c 0x18c314000 + 2601564
21  UIKit                           0x000000018c8084b0 0x18c314000 + 5194928
22  UIKit                           0x000000018c31f148 0x18c314000 + 45384
23  UIKit                           0x000000018c80840c 0x18c314000 + 5194764
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c5463e4 0x18c314000 + 2302948
25  UIKit                           0x000000018c58e7bc 0x18c314000 + 2598844
26  UIKit                           0x000000018c58e654 0x18c314000 + 2598484
27  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000104a22380 0x104614000 + 4252544
28  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001049da674 0x104614000 + 3958388
29  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010466caf0 0x104614000 + 363248
30  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001049f17b4 0x104614000 + 4052916
31  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010492c6c8 0x104614000 + 3245768
32  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001056f0748 0x104614000 + 17680200
33  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010576dc00 0x104614000 + 18193408
34  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010577141c 0x104614000 + 18207772
35  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010463cc6c 0x104614000 + 167020
36  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010463d410 0x104614000 + 168976
37  Foundation                      0x000000018319a0ec 0x183081000 + 1151212
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826f7404 0x182609000 + 975876
39  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826f6c2c 0x182609000 + 973868
40  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826f479c 0x182609000 + 964508
41  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182614da8 0x182609000 + 48552
42  GraphicsServices                0x00000001845f9020 0x1845ee000 + 45088
43  UIKit                           0x000000018c631758 0x18c314000 + 3266392
44  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000104acdb00 0x1046bc000 + 4266752
45  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000104a6dd7c 0x1046bc000 + 3874172
46  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000104a6dd3c 0x1046bc000 + 3874108
47  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010470cf74 0x1046bc000 + 331636
48  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001049d46c8 0x1046bc000 + 3245768
49  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000105798748 0x1046bc000 + 17680200
50  MyApp.Ios                   0x0000000105815c00 0x1046bc000 + 18193408
51  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010581b978 0x1046bc000 + 18217336
52  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010577b208 0x1046bc000 + 17560072
53  MyApp.Ios                   0x00000001058df5b8 0x1046bc000 + 19019192
54  MyApp.Ios                   0x000000010470c7fc 0x1046bc000 + 329724
55  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001820a5fc0 0x1820a5000 + 4032
```

I have tried anything I have found on net:

1. Delete `obj` and `bin` dirs
2. Recreate from scratch the `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.
3. Update all libs to the latest
4. Reinstall VS
5. Reinstall Xcode

I am using the following libs in my app:

1. google signup
2. xamarin auth
3. ffimageloading
4. newtonsoft.json

My Visual studio is the latest version and this is my release settings:

[image]

This crash has never happened to me on simulator as well as on my IPhone 7.
Is there and idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you giving compile bitcode option?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I'm not sure what is `compile bitcode`, but according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317580/enable-bitcode-in-xamarin-ios) this capability is not possible with xamarin.ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strange bug in the current VS 2017 mac; when I open my storyboard it will open as IPhone 8 plus board. When I change it to IPhone 4s, on some of the times it will removes the name of specific `UITableView`. This leads to `Null pointer exception`.

I don't know why VS does this but this is the source of my problem.

BTW, It happens only when my build configuration is Debug/Release - IPhone.